# pyspark extracting a string using python

Tags: python, pyspark

Spark dataframe which has column `emailID`  : `ram.shyam.78uy@testing.com`. i would like to extract the string between "." and "@"  i.e `78uy` and store it in column.
tried

```
split_for_alias = split(rs_csv['emailID'],'[.]') 
rs_csv_alias= rs_csv.withColumn('alias',split_for_alias.getItem(size(split_for_alias) -2))
```

Its adding `78uy@testing` as alias. Another column can be added and chop off the extra values. But is it possible to do in single statement.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the alphanumeric immediately to the left of special character `.` and immediately followed by special character `@`

DataFrame

```
data= [
      (1,"am.shyam.78uy@testing.com"),
      (2, "j.k.kilo@jom.com")
    ]

df=spark.createDataFrame(data, ("id",'emailID'))

df.show()

+---+--------------------+
| id|             emailID|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|am.shyam.78uy@tes...|
|  2|    j.k.kilo@jom.com|
+---+--------------------+
```

Code

```
df.withColumn('name', regexp_extract('emailID', '(?<=\.)(\w+)(?=\@)',1)).show()
```

outcome

```
+---+--------------------+----+
| id|             emailID|name|
+---+--------------------+----+
|  1|am.shyam.78uy@tes...|78uy|
|  2|    j.k.kilo@jom.com|kilo|
+---+--------------------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

We made the [Fugue project](https://github.com/fugue-project/fugue) to port native Python or Pandas code to Spark or Dask. This lets you can keep the logic very readable by expressing it in native Python. Fugue can then port it to Spark for you with one function call.

First we setup a Pandas DataFrame to test:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2],"email": ["am.shyam.78uy@testing.com", "j.k.kilo@jom.com"]})
```

Next, we make a native Python function. The logic is clear this way.

```py
from typing import List, Dict, Any
def extract(df:List[Dict[str,Any]]) -> List[Dict[str,Any]]:
    for row in df:
        email = row["email"].split("@")[0].split(".")[-1]
        row["new_col"] = email
    return df
```

Then we can test on the Pandas engine:

```py
from fugue import transform
transform(df, extract, schema="*, new_col:str")
```

Because it works, we can bring it to Spark by supplying an engine:

```
import fugue_spark
transform(df, extract, schema="*, new_col:str", engine="spark").show()
```

```
+---+--------------------+-------+
| id|               email|new_col|
+---+--------------------+-------+
|  1|am.shyam.78uy@tes...|   78uy|
|  2|    j.k.kilo@jom.com|   kilo|
+---+--------------------+-------+
```

Note `.show()` is needed because Spark evaluates lazily. This `transform` can take in both Pandas and Spark DataFrames and will output a Spark DataFrame if using the Spark engine.